# "Even this means" VS "Even though this means"

Tags: grammaticality, compound-complex

> 1. Medical workers exhibited their dedication to saving lives, *even **though** this meant* they had to put themselves in harm's way.
> 2. Medical workers exhibited their dedication to saving lives, *even this meant* they had to put themselves in harm's way.

I want to know which of these is correct.

Comment: The question title says "means" but your example sentences say "meant".

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct. The  ‘though’ is necessary if you want to show that they did it *despite the fact* that it put them in harm’s way; that they were being selfless. Additionally, you need a conjunction between the two clauses

> Medical workers exhibited their dedication to saving lives

and

> this meant they had to put themselves in harm's way.

Otherwise, the sentence isn’t coherent at all.

Comment: Can I say "Medical workers worked tirelessly to save lives during this the unprecedented health crisis, even this meant they had to put themselves in harm's way."?

Comment: No. There has to be a ‘though’ between ‘this’ and ‘meant. Otherwise the sentence is correct.

Comment: The second sentence could be correct but it wouldn't have the same meaning.